# %j specifier in console.log excludes some properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, console.log

I was recently trying to load the `bson` (binary JSON) module in `node.js`.  The API docs were unclear, so I thought inspecting the objects would help me.  The results of the inspection were baffling.

Finally I found out it was because I was using `%j` which "lies" -- it doesn't print all of an object's dictionary keys!  (I am using Python terminology for "attributes" as things referenced with a dot, and "dictionary keys" for things referenced with brackets, because I don't know the proper names for these things in JS.)

Here is an example:

```
var bson = require("bson");
console.log("bson as %%j: %j", bson);
console.log("bson as console.log: ", bson);
```

And here's the output:

```
bson as %j: {"BSONPure":{},"BSONNative":{}}
bson as console.log:  { BSONPure: 
   { Code: [Function: Code],
     Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
     BSON: 
      { [Function: BSON]
        BSON_INT32_MAX: 2147483647,
        BSON_INT32_MIN: -2147483648,
        BSON_INT64_MAX: 9223372036854776000,
        BSON_INT64_MIN: -9223372036854776000,
...
```

I thought since `x.key` is the same as `x["key"]`, that this means attributes and dictionary keys are "the same thing" in JS.  I found after experimenting that `BSON.BSONPure` is `{}`, however `BSON.BSONPure.BSON` and `BSON.BSONPure["BSON"]` are a `function` object!

This leads me to believe that whatever `"%j"` does, must somehow be excluding some keys.  How does it decide which keys to exclude?  Why would it even do that?  JS is a really confusing language sometimes!

Related Github ticket:  https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues/97

Comment: Both things are the same (as you say, `x.key` and `x["key"]` are totally equivalent), and they're called *properties*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Down in the `node.js` [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L280), the `%j` placeholder results in a call to `JSON.stringify()` on the passed argument.

The thing is, in passing your `bson` variable, you are not passing an valid `JSON` object. You are passing a node.js module which among other things has exported functions.

So, what happens when `JSON.stringify()` hits a function?

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion
>   it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to
>   null (when it is found in an array). ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify))

So the behaviour you are seeing is completely expected, you are trying to log something as `JSON` that is not valid `JSON`.

```
> JSON.stringify({name: "Bob"}) 
> "{"name":"Bob"}"

> JSON.stringify({func: function(){}}) 
> "{}"
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense.  When I printed out some object, I tried doing `console.log("x is "+x)` which gave the unhelpful `x is [object Object]`.  So I googled how to print stuff out in JS, and the answer I looked at told me to use %j, which worked for the particular example.  But then I started using %j as "the JS version of Python's repr()" without actually reading what it does.  Thanks for the reference to the docs

Comment: The referenced `node.js` source file has changed.  This appears to be the canonical URL for what was most likely the version at the time of the last edit: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/3e44b8c91ef717913364ac67a12cb7cd638630db/lib/util.js#L280

(I would edit the answer, except that I get an error that the "Suggested edit queue is full".)